# AngularJS: Filter Too Lax - incorrect display

Tags: angularjs

I have an object of attachments returned from a SharePoint custom list with each named as ProjectID | RequestID | TaskID | Filename.

I am trying to filter according to my needs (only 1 ID will be present with the filename and the rest are usually 0 unless there is sharing going on) but when I filter where PID (Project ID) == 1, it displays where PID is 1 AND 17. How do I tighten up the filter to match EXACT?

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ct52NUvJhTarySi5nDRf?p=preview).

Here is my HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h3>All Attachments:</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="att in attachments">{{att.Title}}</li>
    </ul>
    <hr />
    <h3>Attachments for Project #1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="pat in fstProj = (attachments | filter:{PID:'1'})">{{pat.Title}}</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

and here is the Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, catFactory) {

  $scope.attachments = catFactory.getAttachments();


});
```

Comment: Please, take a look at my updated answer. Also, feel free to upvote the answer as well if you really like it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter` filter uses string-matching. sinc eyou want to compare exact numbers, you can filter by a user-defined function:

```
<li ng-repeat="pat in attachments | filter:byPID">{{pat.Title}}</li>

$scope.byPID = function (item) {
    return item.PID === 1;
}
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/G7eoZJoi8r5PxcdwUlVs?p=preview)**.

---

**UPDATE:**

Of course, if you are willing to use a more recent version of Angular (not from the 1.0.* branch) (**which you absolutely should**), there is a third paramter to be passed to `filter`, in order to do strict matching (instead of substring):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js" ...>
...
<li ng-repeat="pat in attachments | filter:{PID:1}:true">{{pat.Title}}</li>
```

In this case, nothing else needs to be changed.

See, also, this **[other demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UBBFqbRmihP494yAsYNy?p=preview)**.